# How to convert the first row of the dataframe to a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, row, col

i'm working with pandas, and im trying to convert the first row of the dataframe to a column, i have tried the stack() function, but it looks like f%#¤ed. I cannot really use stack() since i have columns of different headers. let's say, your data frame looks like following: (red box: how my dataframe looks like (yellow box: how i want my dataframe to look like)
[image]

I'm gratefull if you can help me.

Cheers,

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Comment: Or do you need `df = df.iloc[0].to_frame()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('a','b','c')).reorder_levels([2,0,1]).sort_index() 
print (df)
c     a  b 
2014  A  A1    1
         A1    9
      B  B1    9
         B2    1
2015  A  A1    5
         A1    4
      B  B1    1
         B2    7
2016  A  A1    5
         A1    1
      B  B1    6
         B2    7
dtype: int64
```

And if need `columns` from `Multiindex`:

```
df = df.stack()
       .rename_axis(('a','b','c'))
       .reorder_levels([2,0,1])
       .sort_index()
       .reset_index(name='count')
print (df)

       c  a   b  count
0   2014  A  A1      1
1   2014  A  A1      9
2   2014  B  B1      9
3   2014  B  B2      1
4   2015  A  A1      5
5   2015  A  A1      4
6   2015  B  B1      1
7   2015  B  B2      7
8   2016  A  A1      5
9   2016  A  A1      1
10  2016  B  B1      6
11  2016  B  B2      7
```

EDIT:

There is problem you need convert first and second column to `Multiindex` by parameter `index_col`:

```
tab3 = "C:\\Users\\abk29\\NordicMontlyDemand\\NordicDY\\Book1.xls"
df = pd.read_excel(tab3, sheetname="Sheet1", skiprows=2, index_col=[0,1])
print (df)
              2016  2017  2018
  Unnamed: 1                  
A A1             1     1     1
  A2             2     2     2
B B1             3     3     3
  B2             4     4     4
df = df.stack().rename_axis(('a','b','c')).reorder_levels([2,0,1]).sort_index()
print (df)
c     a  b 
2016  A  A1    1
         A2    2
      B  B1    3
         B2    4
2017  A  A1    1
         A2    2
      B  B1    3
         B2    4
2018  A  A1    1
         A2    2
      B  B1    3
         B2    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: still very strange result :/

Comment: it's a very nice solution, however the stack function is the main key/problem, it's saying i only have one levels and not Three, so i can not reorder it...

Comment: Ok, waht is `print (df.info)` of your original dataframe?

Comment: what i actually do is i'm Reading the data from an excel file, that looks exacly like the data frame in the red box (Picture above). And it's Reading it correctly, the stacking function is so strange in this case.

Comment: I am not sure what is strange, can you add your output after stack ?

Comment: Ok, if is possible, can you send me your file to my email in my profile?

Comment: i have sent an email to you. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for upvote, but for accepting need click to empty nike tick under `1` for green color. then get +2 points. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:

```
In [199]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [200]: df
Out[200]:
   a  b  c
0  4  4  0
1  3  3  0
2  4  3  3
3  3  2  0
4  1  0  4

In [201]: df.columns
Out[201]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')

In [202]: df, df.columns, df.columns.name = df.iloc[1:], df.iloc[0].astype(str), None

In [203]: df
Out[203]:
   4  4  0
1  3  3  0
2  4  3  3
3  3  2  0
4  1  0  4

In [204]: df.columns
Out[204]: Index(['4', '4', '0'], dtype='object')
```